# Setting/changing geometry type for .TAB file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry-conversion, multipart, tab

I have a *.TAB*-file with MultiLines. When I load it to QGIS, in layer properties it says Geometry: Line (LineString) which is wrong. When I try to do some operations with geometries (like snap to layer) QGIS breaks all geometries into single lines.

I've tried to:

1. Save the layer with the "force multi-type" option enabled
2. Create a memory layer with multi-type geometry and save it as *.TAB*
3. Create a *.TAB* with one multiline geometry feature

None of the options worked.

My final goal is just to save processed multi-type geometries back to *.TAB* file without splitting into single-type.

Comment: What format is the geometry in your *.TAB* file, is it WKT?

Comment: @Matt This is Mapinfo format. The question about how QGIS handles this type of source. I've already found out how to save my geometries with PyQgis and seems like no way to do it via GUI.

Comment: Hi @BlackTesta Can you add your solution with PyQGIS as an answer to your own question, please? I will vote your answer up. It will be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer to my question. But @KVO asked for PyQGIS solution. Here is mine:

```
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    source = layer.source()
    ext=source.split('|')[0].rpartition('.')[-1]
    if ext.lower() == 'tab':
        if layer.geometryType() == 2:
            newSource=source.replace('geometrytype=Polygon','geometrytype=MultiPolygon')
        elif layer.geometryType() == 1:
            newSource=source.replace('geometrytype=LineString','geometrytype=MultiLineString')
        layer.setDataSource(newSource,layer.name(),'ogr')
        layer.reload()
        layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. What is about you question: the last QGIS version, which supported multipart geometry of TAB files was QGIS 3.12.3 Bucuresti. Because the editing tool Add part worked in it with TAB files. And in the version 3.14 Pi it was already unabled. I made a bug report on Github https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46644  But in the recent QGIS versions adding part was broken even for geopackage layers. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/54611

Comment: I haven't received your response a month ago, I only accidentally saw this post just now. Unfortunately, this @ symbol seems to be not working too. Everything was broken)))